# Using hta copy data from access database to excel

Tags: sql, ms-access, vbscript, hta

Using hta, I am trying to pull data from access database and want to paste in new excel file. Below is the code which i have try but i have no clue how to open new excel file and how to paste query data to that excel file.

Below is the code which i have try.

```vb
Dim conn 'GLOBAL doing this here so that all functions can use it
sub dotheconnection
    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    conn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source= C:\Users\Database\data.mdb;User Id=; Password="
    If conn.errors.count <> 0 Then 
        alert("problem connecting to the database")
    end if
end Sub


sub Search
   SQL_query = "SELECT * FROM dvd WHERE agent = 'Sharath Chandra Das' "
    Set rsData = conn.Execute(SQL_query)
    'Here i want a code which should open new excel file and output should paste in this excel file
end Sub
```

Comment: Why accept that answer if you are just [going to cherry pick from it](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/53078942/4) the bits that *"might"* work in VBScript? That whole answer will not work in VBScript so please don't mark it as accepted as it's confusing to others looking for a true VBScript solution.

Comment: Ok, Lankymart i will take care.

Comment: I disagree with the closure of this question as no MCVE. This is not a debugging question, the code serves only to provide context, show effort, and show that OP does know how to create a recordset that holds the desired data, and only needs help exporting that recordset.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth you answered the question in its original form, so that doesn't surprise me.

Comment: @Lankymart Yup, just stating my reasons out in the open for the reopen reviewers to consider, not necessarily directed towards you. I don't answer questions I consider closeworthy of course. Thanks again for pointing out the flaws in my answer, though.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth not my intention, the answer is fine. Just wish people wouldn't be so quick to jump on answering poorly asked questions *(it wasn't clear what language they actually were using for example, which causes confusion itself)*, this is a poorly asked question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to move recordsets to Excel, or to copy data from Access to Excel.

If you want to keep it minimal:

```vb
Dim excelApp
Set excelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
ExcelApp.Workbooks.Add 'New workbook
ExcelApp.Cells(1,1).CopyFromRecordset rsData
ExcelApp.Visible = True
```

Personally, I use the following code:

```vb
Public Sub RecordsetToExcel(rs)
    Dim excelApp
    rs.MoveFirst
    Set excelApp = GetOrCreateObject("Excel.Application")
    excelApp.Visible = True
    excelApp.Workbooks.Add
    excelApp.ActiveSheet.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs
    excelApp.WindowState = -4137 'xlMaximized
    Dim i
    For i = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
        excelApp.ActiveSheet.Cells(1, i + 1).Value = rs.Fields(i).Name
        excelApp.ActiveSheet.Cells(1, i + 1).Columns.AutoFit
    Next
    With excelApp.ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(1, excelApp.ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion, , , 1) 'xlSrcRange, xlYes
        .Name = TableName
        .TableStyle = "TableStyleLight1"
    End With
End Sub
```

Where GetOrCreateObject is the following function:

```vb
Public Function GetOrCreateObject(Class)
    On Error Resume Next
    Set GetOrCreateObject = GetObject("", Class)
    If err.Number <> 0 Then
         Set GetOrCreateObject = CreateObject(Class)
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: The question is tagged [tag:vbscript] and [tag:hta], this code sample is [tag:vba] how is it going to work in an HTA?

Comment: @Lankymart Sorry, I've adjusted the code to be vbscript compatible

Comment: That is not VBScript compatible. Still typed declarations in the code, your `GetOrCreateObject()` function will fail because error handling in VBScript does not support `Goto label` only `On Error Resume Next` and `On Error Goto 0`. That is my issue with VBA answers being given to VBScript questions, it may seem like they are the same but they are not. Again, the question is unclear, doesn't provide enough information to answer correctly in the first place.

Comment: Hi Erik,Thanks for the help its work like a charm!!!!

Comment: @saransh Are you using VBScript or VBA?, your questions make no sense and comments like this are misleading! Which bit *"work like a charm"*, because I guarantee the `GetOrCreateObject()` function will fail in VBScript.

Comment: Hi Lankymart i am using VBScript with hta i have edit my code using Erik code and its working i am getting data in excel.

Comment: @Lankymart Sorry, my VBScript is rusty at best, and I'm experienced in VBA so I sometimes make some errors. Will try to do more extensive testing next time

Comment: @saransh no you didn't, you cherry picked a small piece. Erik has now modified it so it may work in it's entirety, but before that edit it wouldn't, but you still accepted it??